# Google SQL Mysql foreign data wrapper error to connect another Google SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to set Foreign Data Wrapper using MySQL CREATE SERVER Command  to connect from one Google Cloud MySQL to another Google Cloud MySQL server
But receiving error as :

[SQL] CREATE SERVER my_production_fed_link
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql
OPTIONS (USER 'abcddxxxxx', PASSWORD 'xxxxxxxxx' , HOST 'destination-ip-address', PORT 9306, DATABASE 'destination-server-database');

[Err] 1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

---

I tried with port 3306 as well but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

what it basically is trying to tell you is ...

login to mySQL as user `root` and then run the query statement again.

```
mysql -u root -p...
```